# Python Pandas -- Create dataframe column based off of its own previous value in earlier rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
A B
0 1
1 2 
2 3
3 4
```

I now want to create a column C which does some operations on the values in A and B, but also be the basis for future values.

So, for example a row in C = (prev_value_in_C)/(B+A)

So let's say I initialize first row to have value 5. Then it would look something like

```
A B C
0 1 5
1 2 5/3    = 1.67
2 3 1.67/5 = .334
3 4 .334/7 =.047
```

I'm trying to understand if rolling or expanding can be used -- or if such an operation WITHOUT using for loops is possible directly through the present pd tools.

Something sort of like:

df['C'] = df['C'].shift()/(df['A'] + df['B'])

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a command in the pandas DataFrame.
I think a for loop is the best idea, looping as many times as there are rows.
Then retrieving the C-value of the row before that, doing the calculation and replacing the C-value of the row it is working on.

Answer (score 0):

I think here are necessary loops, because recursive calculations are not vectorisable, for improve performance is used  [**numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba):

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, b, first):
    c = np.empty(a.shape)
    c[0] = first
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        c[i] = c[i-1] / (a[i] + b[i])
    return c

df['C'] = f(df['A'].to_numpy(), df['B'].to_numpy(), 5)
print (df)
   A  B         C
0  0  1  5.000000
1  1  2  1.666667
2  2  3  0.333333
3  3  4  0.047619
```

Performance in small DataFrame, `4k rows`:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, b, first):
    c = np.empty(a.shape)
    c[0] = first
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        c[i] = c[i-1] / (a[i] + b[i])
    return c


In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: df['C1'] = f(df['A'].to_numpy(), df['B'].to_numpy(), 5)
    ...: 
    ...: 
213 µs ± 7.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [46]: %%timeit
    ...: 
    ...: df['C2'] = 5
    ...: for i in range(1, len(df)):
    ...:     df.loc[i, 'C2'] = df.loc[i-1, 'C2'] / (df.loc[i, 'A'] + df.loc[i, 'B'])
    ...:     
2.28 s ± 51.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
df['C'] = 5
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'C'] = df.loc[i-1, 'C'] / (df.loc[i, 'A'] + df.loc[i, 'B'])
```

Output:-

```
   A  B         C
0  0  1  5.000000
1  1  2  1.666667
2  2  3  1.000000
3  3  4  0.714286
```